# Get the Previous Month days count

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date

How can I get the previous Month total days Count?

> i.e = Current Month is June, So I want May month Total number of
>   days.(Output = 31)

This is what I've tried but it's not working.

`let PrevDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())`

Comment: Its a very common question and you can find the solution by searching on google for 1-2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is the usage :

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date1 = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())! // -1 mean previous month

let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date1)!
let numDays = range.count
print(numDays)
```

OUTPUT :

```
31
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Calendar.current.range`, take a look below .

```
let range = Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: PrevDate)!

let numDays = range.count
```

Answer (score 0):

What you got is just a date exactly month ago, to get number of days in the month you would go one step further:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

let prevDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())!
let numberOfDaysInPreviousMonth = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: prevDate)?.count
```

And that's all, you have your count in `numberOfDaysInPreviousMonth`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let currentDate = Date()
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: currentDate)
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: currentDate)
let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month - 1)
let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!

let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date)!
let numDays = range.count
print(numDays)
```

Here you can change the year also according to your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why're you making `Date` object multiple times?